# Where clause and multiple parameters C#?

Tags: c#, sql, inner-join, where-clause

Is it possible combine a WHERE clause that takes two different parameters? I have to pass two parameters to this query for the join.

Here is my code:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    string sSQL = "SELECT * FROM head_doc h INNER JOIN doc_details d ON h.id_doc = d.id_doc INNER JOIN clients c ON c.id_client = h.id_client WHERE t.id_doc="+  Session["id_doc"].ToString()+  "AND id_client="+ Session["id_client"].ToString());
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sSQL, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(dt);
}
```

Apparently I can't do this as `mysql` rejects this syntax. How can I do it differently?

Comment: What error message you get exactly?

Comment: It rejects the syntax because You have no spaces. "AND - You need a whitespace before that

Comment: Agree with @MajkeloDev. Please not that it's recommentded to use parameters instead of concatenating values in the command

Answer (score 2):

you need quotes and a space:

```
 string sSQL = "SELECT * FROM head_doc h INNER JOIN doc_details d ON h.id_doc = d.id_doc INNER JOIN clients c ON c.id_client = h.id_client WHERE t.id_doc='"+  Session["id_doc"].ToString()+  "' AND id_client='"+ Session["id_client"].ToString()+"'");
```

However better use parameters:

```
string sSQL = "SELECT * FROM head_doc h INNER JOIN doc_details d ON h.id_doc = d.id_doc INNER JOIN clients c ON c.id_client = h.id_client WHERE t.id_doc=@par1 AND id_client=@par2");

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sSQL, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par1", Session["id_doc"].ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par2", Session["id_client"].ToString());
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        ...
```

**EDIT:**
if indeed id_client field exists in both tables use:

```
string sSQL = "SELECT * FROM head_doc h INNER JOIN doc_details d ON h.id_doc = d.id_doc INNER JOIN clients c ON c.id_client = h.id_client WHERE t.id_doc=@par1 AND h.id_client=@par2");
```

Comment: I am using parameters as you suggested, but I get an error: id_client in where clause is ambiguous....

Comment: Also, using `ToString()` on parameters != necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
"AND id_client
```

To

```
" AND id_client
```

It could be a problem with the missing space after the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible yes, and best suggestion here is one by Nerd Nord mentioning parameters.
However i noticed "t.id_doc" which implicates id_doc comes from table t, and in your select i see no table with alias t.
So use parameters syntax, and find a proper table alias for your id_doc.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all. Here's the (working) code I used eventually.

```
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            string sSQL = "SELECT * FROM head_doc h INNER JOIN doc_details d ON h.id_doc = d.id_doc INNER JOIN clients c ON c.id_clients = h.id_clients WHERE h.id_doc=@par1 AND c.id_client=@par2";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sSQL, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@par1", Session["id_doc"].ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@par2", Session["id_client"].ToString()));
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);
        }
```